# HttpResponse to JSON

Tags: java, xml, json, httpresponse

I'm executing the following:

```
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
getMethod.addHeader("Accept","application/x-oslc-cm-change-request+json");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(getMethod);
```

where the URL is pointing to an XML file, which is:

```
<oslc_cm:Collection oslc_cm:totalCount="1">
    <rtc_cm:Project rdf:resource="https://private"/>
</oslc_cm:Collection>
```

Next, I execute

```
InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
String json = convertStreamToString(is);
JSON jsonObject = JSONSerializer.toJSON(json);
```

At the last line, I get an exception, JSONException: Invalid JSON String.

Is there something that I'm not doing, or missing something?

The variable json contains the http response, which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
a comment

-->

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<title></title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/jazz/web/_style/?inclu
VelSxGN_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fjazz">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/jazz/web/net.jazz.ajax/jazz.ico">

<style type="text/css">
#net-jazz-ajax-NoScriptMessage {
    width: 100%;
    color: #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    z-index: 999;
}
    </style>

</head>

<body class="tundra">
    <noscript><div id="net-jazz-ajax-NoScriptMessage">Javascript is disabled or not available in your Browser</div></noscript>
<div id="net-jazz-ajax-InitialLoadMessage">Loading...</div>
<div id="net-jazz-ajax-WorkbenchRoot"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        djConfig = {
                isDebug: false,
                usePlainJson: true,
                baseUrl: "/jazz/web/dojo/",
                locale: "en-us",
                localizationComplete: true
        };
        /*null*/
        net = {jazz: {ajax: {}}};
        net.jazz.ajax._contextRoot = "/jazz";
        net.jazz.ajax._webuiPrefix = "/web/";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jazz/web/_js/?include=Z~&eten_US"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

dojo.getObject('jazz.core.loader', true)._loaded=['Z'];
net.jazz.ajax._rootServices = 'https://private';

net.jazz.ajax._storageService = 'https://private';

net.jazz.ajax._queryService = 'https://private';

net.jazz.ajax._infoCenterRoot = 'https://private';

net.jazz.ajax._oauthRealmName = 'Jazz';

net.jazz.ajax._viewletServiceRoot = 'https://private';

net.jazz.ajax._viewletWebUIRoot = 'https://private';

net.jazz.ajax._hasLocalRepository = true;
net.jazz.ajax._proxyLegacyMode = false;
net.jazz.ajax._oauthDomains = ['https://private']

net.jazz.ajax._friendDomains = ['https://private']


/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
        dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
                net.jazz.ajax.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbencweb.app.authrequired");
        });
/* ]]> */
</script>
</body>
</html
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to parse XML like it's JSON, then?

Comment: did you print out json? what did it contain?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to convert the XML inside the String `json` to JSON? This will not work.

Comment: I added the output of the HTTP response (which is the variable json)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something.  You are trying to parse XML as JSON, even though the formats are completely different.  Use an XML parser like [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/) instead of a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);
```